# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

The result of 'mysql_query' is a resource, right? Then why am I getting this error:
**Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given**
on this piece of code?
CODE:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root")or die("NO");
mysql_select_db($db_name,$con)or die("Not good");


$usernames=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username='$user' AND Password='$password'");


$count=mysql_num_rows($usernames);

if($count==1){session_register("user");session_register("password");header("location:Login_Success.php");}
else{echo "<p style='color:red'>Wrong username or password!</p>";}
```

Also, I have a problem with my if...else statement. The else code appears before the if's.

Comment: **http://bobby-tables.com**

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar then how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mysql connect should be like that

```
     mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysql_password');
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----you forgot this
```

you forgot password.

and you should not use mysql but instead use PDO or MYSQLI.

if you use `mysql_error()` you can see whats wrong easilly .
like that:

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mysql_password")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: it's nothing wrong with the connect! and i get the same results if i use mysqli

Comment: try add this after your query `if(!$usernames) mysql_error() ;` and say what error you got.

Comment: thanks @echo_me it said that the table doesn't exist!

Comment: nice then you know whats the problem :) , table doesnt exist. if its solved make sure to accept answer.

Comment: hey guys it was a problem in phpmyadmin i messed up the tables.

Comment: oh and @echo_Me i don't have enough reputation to accept the answer.      :(